# How to change the background upon click?

Tags: html, onclick, background-image, spry

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_effectAppearFade(targetElement, duration, from, to, toggle)
{
    Spry.Effect.DoFade(targetElement, {duration: duration, from: from, to: to, toggle: toggle});
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Backgrounds/Real Main Menu.png')">  
<div class="CollapsiblePanel" id="CollapsiblePanel1">
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">
    <p><center>
      <img src="Backgrounds/Main Menu.png" alt="Main Menu" width="624" height="97" id="Enter" onclick="MM_effectAppearFade(this, 2000, 100, 0, false)"/>
    </center></p>
  </div>
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">
    <center>
      <img id="Background" src="Backgrounds/Title.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="The website has not loaded properly due to your internet, sorry" />
    </center>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1");
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

That is my website so far.
I would like to have the background colored black (I can do that :P).

However, on click of the collapsible panel, I would like the background to change to an image, more specifically, to this:

```
background: url('Backgrounds/Practise.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(Backgrounds/Practise.png);
overflow:hidden;
```

I've tried all of the methods I could find on this site.
The function MM_effectAppearFade is called when the panel is clicked, so I'd like to include the code in there.

**Edited Code not working:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
/*body {
    background: url('Backgrounds/Practise.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(Backgrounds/Practise.png);
    overflow:hidden;
}*/
.newBackground{
background: url('Backgrounds/Practise.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(Backgrounds/Practise.png);
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<script src="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_effectAppearFade(targetElement, duration, from, to, toggle)
{
    Spry.Effect.DoFade(targetElement, {duration: duration, from: from, to: to, toggle: toggle});
}
//-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script src="js/jquery.js">

$('.CollapsiblePanel').click(function(){

$('body').addClass('newBackground');

});
</script>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Backgrounds/Real Main Menu.png')">  
<div class="CollapsiblePanel" id="CollapsiblePanel1">
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">
    <p><center>
      <img src="Backgrounds/Main Menu.png" alt="Main Menu" width="624" height="97" id="Enter" onclick="MM_effectAppearFade(this, 2000, 100, 0, false)"/>
    </center></p>
  </div>
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">
    <center>
      <img id="Background" src="Backgrounds/Title.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="The website has not loaded properly due to your internet, sorry" />
    </center>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1");
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anyway you can replicate this in a [jsfiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your new style in your html and use jquery to listen to the click event to the collapsible slider and then use `addClass()` to implement your new background css.

Inlcude the css to your html like so,

```
<style>
.newBackground{
background: url('Backgrounds/Practise.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(Backgrounds/Practise.png);
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

and then on your jquery do like this,

```
$('.CollapsiblePanel').click(function(){

$('body').addClass('newBackground');


});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I click on the Panel and the background doesn't change.

Comment: Did you download and include jQuery from http://jquery.com/download/ to your file?

Comment: You have to include jquery in to your file, else it wont work.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I've added my changes above in my question. Any help? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36740/discussion-between-ronny-and-shivam-malhotra)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery addclass() function

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/